# Function to create a json from 2 json api and apply on every axis

Tags: python, json, pandas

My First column of df is uid, second column url_json1, third_column is url_json2, expected out is in fourth column. The `key` inside url_json1 and url_json2 are similar. So what ever function we are applying to dataframe on the column it will be applied to all

i have 3 data starting from `uid` starting from `1001` to `1003`

```
uid
1001
1002
1003
```

second_column `url_json1`

data inside first row `url_json1`

```
    {
        "quiz": {
            "sport": {
                "result": {
                    "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                    "answer": "Huston Rocket"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

third_column first row `url_json2`

```
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "result": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in football?",
                "answer": "Chelsea"
            },
            "type": "document"
        }
    }
}
```

Output json

`{
    "1001": {
        "url_1": {
            "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
            "answer": "Huston Rocket"
        },
        "url_2": {
            "question": "Which one is correct team name in football?",
            "answer": "Chelsea"
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json

a = {
        "quiz": {
            "sport": {
                "result": {
                    "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                    "answer": "Huston Rocket"
                }
            }
        }
    }
b = {
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "result": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in football?",
                "answer": "Chelsea"
            },
            "type": "document"
        }
    }
}

df = pd.DataFrame({'uid':['1001','1002'],
                   'url_json1':[json.dumps(a), json.dumps(a)],
                   'url_json2':[json.dumps(b), json.dumps(b)]})
#print (df)
```

Solution for N json columns (DataFrame with `uid` column and all another columns are filled by jsons):

```
def func(x):
    #extract uid to variable
    uid = x.pop('uid')
    #storage for nested dicts
    d = defaultdict(dict)
    #loop by all json columns and update defaultdict
    for i, y in enumerate(x, 1):
        #convert json to dict
        y = json.loads(y)
        d[uid].update({f'url_{i}': y['quiz']['sport']['result']})
    #convert back to json
    return json.dumps(dict(d))

df['new'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
print (df)
    uid                                          url_json1  \
0  1001  {"quiz": {"sport": {"result": {"question": "Wh...   
1  1002  {"quiz": {"sport": {"result": {"question": "Wh...   

                                           url_json2  \
0  {"quiz": {"sport": {"result": {"question": "Wh...   
1  {"quiz": {"sport": {"result": {"question": "Wh...   

                                                 new  
0  {"1001": {"url_1": {"question": "Which one is ...  
1  {"1002": {"url_1": {"question": "Which one is ...
```

If there are only 2 json columns solution is simplify:

```
def func(x):
    d1 = json.loads(x['url_json1'])['quiz']['sport']['result']
    d2 = json.loads(x['url_json2'])['quiz']['sport']['result']
    uid = x['uid']

    d = {uid:{'url_1':d1, 'url_2':d2}}
    return json.dumps(d)

df['new'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```